# Private NPM Repository and hardcoded github URLs

Tags: node.js, npm

NPM packages allow dependencies to hardcode a URL where the dependency is found.
For example [intern depends on dojo](https://github.com/theintern/intern/blob/2.2.2/package.json):

```
"dependencies": {
    "istanbul": "0.2.16",
    "source-map": "0.1.33",
    "dojo": "https://github.com/csnover/dojo2-core/archive/ebfa11ba3972944218623a4bd9d124cb8108d70c.tar.gz",
    "chai": "1.9.1",
    "leadfoot": "1.2.1",
    "digdug": "1.2.1",
    "charm": "0.2.0",
    "diff": "1.1.0"
},
```

We are using a private NPM repository (Nexus Repository Manager) but when we publish a package to it these "non-node package" dependencies are not included and so "npm install" fails. Fetching dependencies from "the cloud" is not an option for us.

Has anyone else come up against this problem and solved it in a scalable way? I'd rather not manually rewrite the package.json for every NPM package that does this to point to some internal URL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a repository manager or cache enable ember/npm/bower builds even during github.com outage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41640048/can-a-repository-manager-or-cache-enable-ember-npm-bower-builds-even-during-gith)